# WordPress: Redirect homepage and other pages to login form

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I want to redirect all pages (with one exception) to the login page of WooCommerce if the user isn't in a specific rore in.

To do this, I'm using the following code:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_all', 99 );

function redirect_all() {

    if (
        is_page('9') or // login page
        is_page('1365') // should be visible without redirect
    ) :

    else :

        wp_redirect( get_permalink('9') );
        die();

    endif;

}
```

It works fine for the page with the ID 1365. But the homepage doesn't redirect to the login page.

Isn't it possible to redirect the homepage or is there an other problem with my code?

Comment: I think it's normal : the login page will also execute this code, so it will be redirected to itself ! Try to add a condition so you don't make redirection if we are at the login page

Comment: sorry, my fault. The problem is, that the homepage doesn't redirect to the login page. I edited my code.